# ASP.NET Core 6: How to intercept all incoming requests to call an external service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I am planning to build a micro frontend to intercept and handle all incoming requests just calling an external service that will render the html that the micro frontend must send in the response body.

So, when calling `https://www.myurl.com/path-of-url-1` or `https://www.myurl.com/subfolder/path-of-url-2` or any other path in the website (IMPORTANT: these url are fake, they don't really exists), it must call `MyRenderService.GetResponse(fullpath)` or something like that to get the html body and response code (ok, not found, etc) to return to the client.

I don't care of the incoming url asked by the client (maybe they are random, don't know yet), but any incoming request must be handled by `MyRenderService`.

What about an approach like this?

**Program.cs**

```
using ShopWeb.Service;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.Run(async context =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(await Renderman.Renderize(context));
});


app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.Run();
```

Comment: sounds you need a reverseproxy, what about ocelot (api gateway)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/architect-microservice-container-applications/direct-client-to-microservice-communication-versus-the-api-gateway-pattern

Comment: I don't think so because I don't care about the url asked by the client. MyRenderService.GetResponse(fullpath) will figure out what to do.

Comment: Create a middleware, all requests go through that. You can return content (or not) from a middleware, continue normal request or stop.

Comment: In VS, just click 'Add new item`  and pick `Middleware.cs`. Remember you have to register Middleware.

Comment: You can read this article to create request middleware based on your needs: https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/conditional-middleware-based-on-request-in-asp.net-core

Comment: @BaRRuKa Your approach is fine. Its perfect for your requirement